# Please help me identify this tree. Is it Box elder?

Tags: identification, trees

[image]

Please help me identify this tree. I think it may be a box elder but I am not certain. Any thoughts or confirmation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: A closeup picture of two or three leafs on a low hanging stem as well as a closeup of the bark on the trunk will be very helpful toward positively identifying this species.

Comment: I vote to close this question because the OP didn't return to add details. This tree can't be identified without at least a closeup photo or description of the leaves.